# Pagination removes AR scopes in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently using [api-pagination](https://github.com/davidcelis/api-pagination) gem with [kaminari](https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari). I also have a simple scope to limit the amount of objects returned. For whatever reason though, the pagination removes the return array of the scope and just gives me a generic paginated array. Has anyone else encountered this?

```
class Album < ApplicationRecord
  scope :by_release_date, -> (limit) { limit(limit) }
end
```

---

```
class Api::AlbumsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    albums = paginate Album.by_release_date(1).per(params[:page])

    render json: Api::AlbumSerializer.new(albums).serialized_json
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of engineersmnky I found out that per is overriding `limit` in my case. With this in mind, the api-pagination gem has an option in their pagination method, `per_page` that helps me accomplish what I'm looking for. In the end it would look something like this:

```
class Album < ApplicationRecord
  scope :by_release_date, -> direction { order("release_date #{direction}") }
end
```

---

```
albums = paginate Album.by_release_date, per_page: params[:per_page]
```